# Error when running bundler install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried running bundle install in our production server, but I encounter this problem:

> Updating
>   git://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job.git
>   fatal: Refusing to fetch into current
>   branch refs/heads/master of non-bare
>   repository An error has occurred in
>   git. Cannot complete bundling.

I have bundler version 0.9.25 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are no older versions of bundler installed
gem list | grep bundler
if there are, leave only the newest

Comment: Hi Tadas,

Thanks for your reply, I actually have one version of bundler installed in my production server. What I did instead is bundle package everything, and then in the server I issued the command 'bundle install vendor' it actually fixed my problem.